# web site en mvc no se puede conectar a la base de datos en azure sql

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc-5, azure

Tengo un sitio en `mvc` que se conecta a una base de datos todo montado en `Azure`, cuando se hace una prueba local del sitio funciona correctamente, pero al hacer el deploy a `Azure` muestra que no se puede conectar el sitio con la `DB`.

el firewall de la base de datos esta habilitado las conexiones a los servicios de azure [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El error es:

> Catastrophic Error in /Login/LoginConfirmed
>
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP
>   Provider, error: 0 - An attempt was made to access a socket in a way
>   forbidden by its access permissions.)

Answer (score 1):

Deberias validar como defines el connection string en la aplicacion

[How to use Azure SQL Database in .NET applications](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-dotnet-how-to-use/)

Usa la opcion `Show connection string` para tomar la conexion que usarias en tu desarrollo

saludos

Answer (score 1):

En la pestaña de configuraciones de tu `web app` existe una sección que te permite agregar cadenas de conexión que sobrescriben la del `web.config`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]config

Asegúrate de que la cadena de conexión tenga el mismo nombre de la de tu `web.config` y de generar una cadena de conexión valida.

¡Saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Justo me acaba de suceder lo mismo, la solución está en que debes ir a la configuración del firewall de Azure.

Una vez allí debes agregar la ip del servidor desde el cual te quieres conectar a la DB (El servidor dónde está tu aplicación Web).

Guardas los cambios y listo.
Suerte.

[image: Firewall Azure]